# Rails 5 api + webpacker: how to launch the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js

I have a vue app and a Rails 5 api application.

I'm using Webpacker gem, and according the gem documentation I have to add

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

to my application layout.

My app is a Rails 5 app created with --api, so I don't have the layout.

I have an `index.html` into my public folder.

Is there a way to create an index.html with a reference to my compiled js files?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. As the webpacker says when launching it, webpack output is served from `https://0.0.0.0:8081/packs/` (my config) and the content is in `public/packs`. So creating a `public/index.html` with the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://0.0.0.0:8081/packs/application.js"></script>` should work.